# Issue with android permission : android.permission.READ_LOGS

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am facing a very different problem with Android permission : ***android.permission.READ_LOGS*** with the target sdk `v22`.

This permission was not present in old version of the app **v1.1** and I introduced this permission in **v1.2** to read logs.

Now, when I **update** the app from v1.1 to v1.2, *manually from the apk placed in the phone locally*, I don't see any warning that there was any new permission added with the newer version of the app and if I install the same version from the Google play store, I see a warning that there is a new permission added with this version of the app.

The more strange thing for me is to see that the phone doesn't show this permission in the permission section in the app settings at all.

Comment: Since this permission is probably useless, I'd get rid of it. Ordinary Android SDK apps cannot hold this permission as of Android 4.1 or so.

Comment: Thanks alot for the response @CommonsWare, I think I should follow you comment.

Comment: @CommonsWare as you being a very senior guy, was just curious to know from you why Android OS was unable to catch this permission while I was trying to update the app manually. Can you make any guess on this so that I could have a solid answer to explain other dev's in the Team ? As I have searched almost everything and can't find any reference to this.

Comment: Well, Android would know that your app could not hold `READ_LOGS`, so the fact that it ignored that permission is not surprising. Perhaps the Play Store does not have equivalent algorithms.

Comment: Gothch you, thanks alot @CommonsWare for your valuable support. Cheers.